# Android accessing my current location always returns latitude: 0.0 and longitude: 0.0

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

As the title suggests, when trying to set the location of my googleMap Object in Android, the location manager returns the location as longitude : 0.0 and latitude 0.0 ( displayed in Toast t ).

The permissions are set correctly in my manifest, and i am currently accessing my location using wifi in my current residence.

code for getting device location:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                }

                /* just un implemented methods */
                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {

                }
                /* end of un implemented methods */
            };

            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);



            map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();

            CameraUpdate position = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
            CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8);

            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            map.moveCamera(position);
            map.animateCamera(zoom);

            Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, "longitiude : " + longitude + " latitude : " + latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
```

Android manifest permissions:

```
 permission android:name="packageName.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

The SupportMapFragment does actually load successfully, just happens to load in the wrong location because of the above. I assume i am doing something horribly wrong, but id appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you testing this on a real phone or in the emulator?

Comment: @SirRichie hey, on a tablet, i sent the code to a member of my group (this is a group task) and they managed to sort it, ill update this post with said solution when i have it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm having the same problem now, but the solution was never posted :(